# What is the best way to store a multidimensional array using doctrine 2?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, doctrine-orm

I'd like to have an array of arrays in a class using Zend and Doctrine2.

So I have a class named `Grid`, which should have an attribute containing an array of arrays of GridItem. These `GridItem`'s also containing a link to an instance of `Product`.

Here's `Grid.php`:

```
/**
* @Entity
* @Table(name="Grid")
*/
class GPos_Model_Grid extends GPos_Doctrine_ActiveEntity {
    /**
    * @Id @Column(type="integer")
    * @GeneratedValue
    */
    private $id;

    /** @Column(type="integer") */
    private $number;

    //THIS IS THE ATTRIBUTE
    private $grid;
}
```

And here's `GridItem.php`:

```
/**
* @Entity
* @Table(name="GridItem")
*/
class GPos_Model_GridItem extends GPos_Doctrine_ActiveEntity {
    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;

    /** @Column(length=7) */
    private $color;

    /** @Column(type="boolean") */
    private $grid;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product")
     * @JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $product;
}
```

So as I said, I'd like the `$grid` attribute to be stored as an ArrayCollection of ArrayCollections of `GridItem`.
However, I can't figure out what annotation I should use to make this happen. The only way I found right now is to create a middle class between `Grid` and `GridItem` that would be something like `GridRow`. So I could have Many-To-One associations between all of them. But this produces a new 'joint' between tables and I'd have a small but still significant performance hit which I can't afford.

Do you guys have any advice on how to do this without that `GridRow` class ? Thus using only `Grid` and `GridItem` ?

Thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally opted for the `GridRow` option as I found no way of storing arrays of arrays..